# Sometimes my site redirects to unwanted site (porn)

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching the last couple weeks and tried to solve a problem with my site but with no success. The problem is that sometimes I get redirected to a porno site (not always the same) when I try to access mine. I'm using Wordpress and I've searched for malicious code snippets in the `index.php`, `header.php` and all theme related files and found nothing that could be doing this.

This is a very hard problem to solve cause it's nearly impossible to reproduce, it just happens sometimes. For example, if you try to access one article from my site and you get redirected that doesn't mean you will always get redirected when accessing that article again (even from another computer), making it very hard to debug.

Do you have an idea how to fix this? Is there any way I can disable redirects to another domain or something?

Before I got redirected to the final site, I was able to see this source:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://xxx.xxx.com/adsort.php?aid=2&atr=dirs"></head><body></body></html>
```

I'm not sure if this is useful since it gives no almost information. Beaware that link can redirect you to porno site.

Comment: can you provide link to your site ?

Comment: Could be adware on your machine

Comment: Wow... can I ask how this bug was reported? :P

Comment: That link needs to have a (possible NSFW) comment ;)

Comment: If you are susceptible to a XSS attack, then posting the relevant code here will let us locate and patch the security hole, but that won't neccessarily stop the existing articles from doing the redirect. Locating the source of the existing attack is, I believe, a question that's better suited as [webmasters.se] than here.

Comment: Has the redirect occurred on multiple computers at multiple locations?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that wordpress is subjective to XSS scripting. Especially if you're using the latest update. The first thing that comes to mind are outdated plugins that do have security vulnerabilities.

1. Have you installed outdated plugins? Try to update the ones that are outdated try to find out if they have (or had) any backdoors. (use google, plugin reviews, etc)
2. If you cant find anything in your filesystem, it may be loaded dynamically. So you should to scan (search for example, that xxx url) ALL tables in your database.
3. Are you sure it's not just adware on your personal computer?

Comment: 1 - I've uptaded wordpress to the latest version (3.7.1). The plugins are up to date (at least there's no newer version)

2- That XXX url varies from time to time, so it won't be easy to find if stored in DB

3- Yes, if it was adware in my pc the same thing would happen when accessing my other sites.

Comment: I'm thinking a smart script will use a general url, without http or www and fetches a page that will provide a random xxx url. The fetched xxx url will then be placed (even by javascript) as a meta refresh tag. What plugins have you loaded?

Comment: Active plugins are:

- Advanced custom fields
- Advanced custom fields repeater field
- Facebook meta tags
- mb.miniAudioPlayer
- Meta Box
- Simple Post Views Counter
- Trim Admin Menu

Comment: Also Wp-polls, wp missed schedule rc2013 and wp no category base